# 401 unauthorized github api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, github-api, vue-resource

Im trying to authenticate to github via a github api in vue js but it returns a 401 unauthorized error,any ideas

```
 sendDetails(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      let that=this;
      var b=that.username+':'+that.password;
      var encodedAuth=b.toString('base64');
      console.log(encodedAuth);
        that.$http.post('https://api.github.com/user',{
            headers: {
                'Authorization' : encodedAuth
            }
        })
        .then(function(response){
           console.log(response);
        });
  }
```

but the same format works using curl

Comment: Basic authentication also prefixes the credentials with `Basic` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization#Examples Perhaps this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sendDetails(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let that=this;
  var b=that.username+':'+that.password;
  var encodedAuth=b.toString('base64');
  console.log(encodedAuth);
    that.$http.post('https://api.github.com/user',{
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encodedAuth
        }
    })
    .then(function(response){
       console.log(response);
    });
}
```